# Mapeo de Tabla Intermedia con Annotations en Java - Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

queria saber que estoy haciendo mal en esta clase, ya que tengo en una DB una entidad llamada `tabla_intermedia` 2 unicos atributos clave: `idTabla` int y `idRelacion` de tipo int tambien.
Esta es la clase de Java pero creo que estoy haciendo mal algo con las anotaciones o algo porque no me graba los resultados cuando corro el programa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tabla_intermedia")
public class Tabla  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 506541142044205877L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idTabla")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idRelacion",nullable=false)
    private Relacion relacion;
    

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Relacion getRelacion() {
        return relacion;
    }

    public void setEntidad(Relacion relacion) {
        this.relacion = relacion;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: muestra tu archivo hibernate.cfg.xml y la parte onetomany de la relacion(Bueno la clase Relacion)